# How can I tell my users that they've entered an old password?

Tags: security, passwords

After reading [this question on SO Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19563/is-it-proper-to-be-informed-that-i-entered-an-old-password), I've been wondering how could I implement such feature.

I'm currently storing passwords in the user table

```
ID  | Email         | Pswd
------------------------------------------
1   | bob@no.domain | Argon2ID hash salted
```

So I would need a `password_history` table of some sort.

```
UID |  Pswd                  | Date                | IP
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1   |  Argon2ID hash salted  | 1454-01-05 21:18:01 | 127.0.0.1
```

If the user's password does not match current password, retrieve all older password and verify against all of them.

This could take some time as Argon2ID password validation takes ~160ms depending of the server.

10 old passwords x 160 ms = 1600ms of verification alone

This method seems inefficient. How could I implement this?

Comment: Do you want to store all of the users old password? I would say you can change the encryption method that uses less time for older password. You can get the old password from the user when they are changing to a new password.

Comment: That would be great but if I use Sha384 for example, should I salt it in case of database dump? I wouldn't want to create a security issue trying to provide a better UX either.

Comment: Storing all of the users password is actually not a good idea if you are worried about security. Maybe just storing the last two passwords should be enough. You can add two more columns to your user table and discard the password history table.

Comment: You 100% should not prevent users from using an old password, nor should you warn users about reusing passwords.  The original concept of such warning came from a world where security people imagined password expiry as a good practice (now known to be false) and assuming users were like computers with perfect memory.  That world is now understood to be fiction, and the old NIST guidance from 2003 has been thrown out in replace of new guidance that favours the user.  Don't confuse being annoying with being secure.

Comment: @kks21199 No, you cannot use a weaker encryption format for old passwords!! They're every bit as sensitive as current passwords.

Comment: @duskwuff That's where my second suggestion comes in. Just store two of the user's last password instead of all of them.

Comment: @duskwuff That's what I thought.

Comment: @kks21199 Limiting the number of stored passwords doesn't help. By _ever_ storing insecure password hashes, you are compromising them permanently.

Comment: @duskwuff I mean storing two passwords with the same encryption as the main password, but personally I don't see a point in having to store old passwords and having more responsibility protecting them as well.

Comment: @TheGreatContini This explanation makes a lot of sense and I totally understand the point. I had in mind the Facebook system, I find it useful. But security wise it may not be in everyone's best interest.

Comment: If you're checking old passwords when the user is changing their password, the time delay isn't a major problem.  If you're doing it when the user is entering their password to gain access, only the current password is relevant and telling an attacker that what they typed is one of the user's old passwords is too valuable information to give away.  Even if the attacker can't get into this system with the password, they can use it as a primary guess on other systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Test fewer passwords. Most of the value of this feature comes from testing perhaps the most recent 1 or 2 passwords, or perhaps the most recent one and one from a longer time ago. Testing any more than that provides very little value to users, and may expose them to more risks.
2. Dial down the strength of your password hash a bit. 160 ms for a password hash is excessive, and may place your server at the risk of a denial of service through many distributed login attempts.